# emulator: process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: sigsegv) android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm getting this error with the Android emulator

> emulator: process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: sigsegv) android studio

I only get this error on Ubuntu 64bit. What should to do? I changed automatic to software but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your virtual device's setting.
**Emulated Performance** - **Automatic** to **Software**